# Prove that $\int_a^bf(x)g(x)\text{d}x=c\int_a^bg(x)\text{d}x$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $ f $ and $ g $ be integrable over $ [a, b] $ with $ g (x) \geq 0 $ for all $ x \in [a, b] $. If $$ m = \inf_ {x \in [a, b]} f (x) \quad \text {and} \quad M = \sup_ {x \in [a, b]} f (x) $$ then there is a number $ c \in [m, M] $ such that $$ \int_a ^ bf (x) g (x) \text {d} x = c \int_a ^ bg (x) \text {d} x.$$ In particular if $ f $ is continuous in $ [a, b] $, then there exists $ x_0 \in [a, b] $ which satisfies that $$ \int_a ^ bf (x) g (x) \text { d} x = f (x_0) \int_a ^ bg (x) \text {d} x. $$

**My attempt**

Note that $ m \leq f (x) \leq M $, for all $ x \ in [a, b] $. Since $ g (x) \geq 0 $, then $$ mg (x) \leq f (x) g (x) \leq Mg (x). $$
From which it follows that $$ m \int_a ^ bg (x) \text {d} x \leq \int_a ^ bf (x) g (x) \text {d} x \leq M \int_a ^ bg (x) \text {d} x. $$

Without loss of generality, let's say $ g (x)> 0$. Then, $$\dfrac{m\int_a^bg(x)\text{d}x}{\int_a^bg(x)\text{d}x}\leq \dfrac{\int_a ^ bf (x) g (x) \text {d} x}{\int_a^bg(x)\text{d}x}\leq \dfrac{M\int_a^bg(x)\text{d}x}{\int_a^bg(x)\text{d}x}.$$ $$m\leq \dfrac{\int_a ^ bf (x) g (x) \text {d} x}{\int_a^bg(x)\text{d}x}\leq M.$$
Let $c=\dfrac{\int_a ^ bf (x) g (x) \text {d} x}{\int_a^bg(x)\text{d}x}.$, then $c\in [m,M]$, and $$c\int_a^bg(x)\text{d}x=\int_a ^ bf (x) g (x) \text {d} x.$$

Is the proof correct? Who can help me in the part where $ f $ is particularly continuous? I don't know how to do that part.

Comment: The proof seems essentially correct, though I don't agree that the assumption $g(x)>0$ is "without loss of generality"; there's a case there that should be handled separately. For the second part, the continuity of $f(x)$ should allow an appeal to the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: Let $ f $ be a continuous function on $ [a, b] $. So for every $ u $ such that $ f (a) <u <f (b) $, there exists $ c \in (a, b) $ such that $ f (c) = u $. That says the mean value theorem, but I have that $$ m \leq \dfrac{\int_a ^ bf (x) g (x) \text {d} x}{\int_a^bg(x)\text{d}x} \leq M. $$
I have to somehow guarantee that $ f (a) = m $ and $ f (b) = M $, or how could I do it?

Comment: Not really: just choose points $a'$ and $b'$ with $f(a')=m$ and $f(b')=M$....

Comment: Then, for mean value theorem. Exist $x_0\in (a',b')\subseteq (a,b)$ such that$ f(x_0)=$... Right?

Comment: Yes—but the intermediate value theorem, not the mean value theorem.